# Data Extension Synchronisation of child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, data-synchronization

I have a task of synchronising object from sales cloud to marketing cloud as DE . The problem is that I only want the child business unit object to be synchronised in marketing cloud. I have used cloud connect and now when I synchronise the object I am getting data from the whole account of sales cloud in data extenstion in marketing cloud. Is there a way to only synchronise the object of a specific business unit in sales cloud to marketing cloud.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you would have to upgrade to multi-org. With multi-org, you would be able to connect the parent with your Salesforce org using one API user and choose which objects should synchronize, and connect the child BU to the same org using a different API user and choose different objects to be synchronized. Take a look here at this example from [Multi-Org Account and User Configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_and_user_configuration.htm&type=5):

[image]

There are many things you should consider before making this change, so take a look at [Multi-Org FAQs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_faqs_for_multi_org.htm&type=5).

This upgrade would require you to change your whole setup, and honestly, I don't think it's worth the hassle just for the sake of synching a single object.

It would be much easier to synchronize that object to Parent and use [SQL Query](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm) activity in [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5) to populate the data from a Synchronized Data Extension to a Shared Data Extension, which would then be accessible from a Child BU.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.